# Xamarin Forms - Webview - Remote Website - Load included javascript file

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms

I have a simple Xamarin Forms project that has a WebView which is used to load an ASP.NET website on our intranet. Currently there is only a Android implementation in the solution.

The website being loaded includes several CSS and Javascript files. The CSS files are being linked via `link rel` tags, while the Javascript files are linked using `script src` tags.

I have put `alert` statements in a script on the page itself, as well as in the linked Javascript file. Using a browser on my computer, both `alert` statements show up, however in the WebView, only the `alert` for the page shows up.

I've also tried using the `WebView.eval` method to call a Javascript method in the linked file as well as one defined on the page itself. Calling the method defined on the page worked, but the one in the linked Javascript file didn't.

All that has lead me to the conclusion that for some reason the WebView isn't loading the Javascript files indicated by the `script src` tags.

From research I have done, there is mention of having to include the Javascript file itself in the Android and iOS projects, but those seemed to be for situations where the WebView source was being set to a constructed website, not pointing to an existing web site.

Here are samples of how the files are linked:
    `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/App_Themes/wms.min.css" />`
    `<script src="/Scripts/wms.js"></script>`

I have tried using absolute paths, which didn't work either:
    `<script src="http://path.to.site/Scripts/wms.js"></script>`

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the the linked javascript files to load and be usable?

Edit: Update, apparently the file was being linked and loaded correctly, it was just being cached by the webview and or the android device or emulator.
Because of that, when I made changes to the javascript file, and tried to use / view those changes via the webview, it wasn't being reflected, since a new copy of the javascript file wasn't pulled from the website.
However, when I gave a new name to the javascript file and linked to that, the webview get the new file, and all my changes were there and it behaved as expected.

So, I will be using the clear cache method outlined here to clear my change when the app starts: http://www.tipsabc.com/2015/xamarin-froms-how-to-clear-webview-cached-files/
That way, every time it starts it will force the webview to get a fresh copy of all the files.

Comment: Are you sure that the webpage has fully loaded all DOM and the scripts from the script tag before you run the evaluate JavaScript `WebView` method?

Comment: I would believe so. The eval method is in an event that is triggered by a separate process, so the website should have been fully loaded by then. In addition, the alerts i placed should have fired when the loading is fined.

Comment: You can debug a `WebView` from Safari on your Mac by enabling Web Inspector Debugging in the device settings: Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> check **Web Inspector**. Then connect the device to your Mac, fire up the app, go to the page that the WebView is on in your app, open Safari on your Mac and head to the **Develop** menu and look for your device's name listed there.

Comment: Hmm, I would have to add an iOS implementation to the project to do that, which may be something I need to do to see what is happening.  
May not help me with the Android issue though, since the webview implementation would be different between the Android and iOS projects.

Comment: My bad, did not see that you were only on Android. You could also add `console.log` JavaScript statements everywhere which is what we had to do.